# Specify which file the webpack runtime should be in

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to configure code splitting in a way that...

- does not include the webpack runtime in all the output files
- does not require an additional `common.chunks.js` file for the webpack run time
- allows me to specify which output file to include the webpack runtime in.

In my specific example, I have a `header.js` file, that needs to run before the rest of the page loads. I would like to specify which modules exist in this file, AND the webpack runtime.

And I have a `bundle.js` file, which is the bulk of the code for my app. Since the webpack runtime will be loaded in `header.js`, I'd like to ensure it's not included in `bundle.js`

My entry point looks something like this

```
entry: {
    header: './src/js/doStuffInHeader.js', //<-- I need webpack in here
    bundle: './src/js/main.js'             //<-- not in here
},
```

The webpack documentation says,

> **Entry chunk**
>   An entry chunk contains the runtime plus a bunch of modules. If the chunk contains the module 0 the runtime executes it. If not, it waits for chunks that contains the module 0 and executes it (every time when there is a chunk with a module 0).
>
> **Normal chunk**
>   A normal chunk contains no runtime. It only contains a bunch of modules. The structure depends on the chunk loading algorithm. I. e. for jsonp the modules are wrapped in a jsonp callback function. The chunk also contains a list of chunk id that it fulfills.

But there aren't any instructions on how to distinguish between a normal chunk and and entry chunk in the webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the Commons Chunk Plugin with multiple entry points to specify your chunks.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  entry: { a: "./a", b: "./b" },
  output: { filename: "[name].js" },
  plugins: [ new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("init.js") ]
}
```

So `init.js` is a file with just your runtime (i.e. header.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify entry that will contain webpack runtime code with `CommonsChunkPlugin`. For example, with `app`, `vendor` and `polyfill` entries it may look like:

```
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    names: [ 'app', 'vendor', 'polyfill', 'webpack' ]
  });
```

The last name (`webpack` here) will become an entry containing webpack runtime.

Comment: Ah, I think I've probably not explained myself correctly. I don't want to specify a file just for the webpack runtime, I want to specify a file that will contains x, y, z AND the webpack runtime. I'll update my question.